# Restart the progress bar for new file download

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form to upload a file. In this form, I have a button. When the user click on the button, my code converts the file while shows a progress bar that when hits 100% show a success message in the screen. It works just fine for the first time that I upload the file. However, when I tried to convert another file, my code does not show the progress bar and neither the message. Is there a way to reset the progress bar and message in order to get the progress bar and the message every time that I file is converted by the user?

I have in JS a function called move(). I call this function in my convert file button.

I tried to use `setTimeout` for doing that, but I am not able to fix it. Please, I appreciate any help.

```
    function move() {
          var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
          width = 1;
          var id = setInterval(frame, 5); //makes slow 
          var timeout=3000;
          function frame() {
            if (width >= 100) {
              clearInterval(id); //stop the bar


            } else {
              width++; 
              elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
              elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
              if(width>=100){
              document.getElementById("status-message").innerHTML = "Sucessfully download the file.";  
               setTimeout(function(){
                  document.getElementById("status-message").innerHTML = 'none';
                  document.getElementById("myProgress").innerHTML = 'none';
                }, timeout);  

              } 

            }  

          }

        }
```

Comment: You need to clean the variable width when the variable is 100. example:

Comment: show the html code, what's the difference between `myProgress` and `myBar`?